# Why doesn't this proof require extensionality? (Agda)

Tags: equality, agda, theorem-proving

The following proves the equality of two functions:

```
η-→ : ∀ {A B : Set} (f : A → B) → (λ (x : A) → f x) ≡ f
η-→ f = refl
```

Why doesn't it need extensionality? How does Agda know that the function to the left of the `≡` simplifies to `f`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(λ x → f x) ≡ f` is a basic rule of definitional equality for functions, called the eta rule. It's built into the type checker. Implementations of type theory commonly support it.

Comment: What's the justification for having eta conversion in, but not having extensionality built in? They seem to have different status, and I'm trying to understand why. Is it because eta conversion is just syntactic?

Comment: Eta equality is decidable, extensional equality is not decidable, nor is it practically effectively semidecidable. Supporting function extensionality as a *provable* theorem is a different matter. Usually it is postulated, more recently it's provable in some systems, e.g. cubical Agda.

Comment: It is fair to say that eta conversion is syntactic, and extensional equality is semantic.

Comment: @MaxHeiber eta conversion has to exist, when you introduce lambda abstraction. Extensional equality doesn't need to exist - there are intensional theories.

Comment: @SassaNF function eta isn't obligatory, lambda abstraction doesn't imply or require eta.

Comment: For future readers: I think this is the sort of proof of extensionality that @András Kovács is referring to: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02108.pdf (Cubical Type Theory: a constructive interpretation of the univalence axiom). There's also discussion of how extensionality follows from univalence in section 4.9 of the Homotopy Type Theory book.

Comment: To summarize: I take it that eta conversion is neither obligatory for computing things nor is eta conversion implied by the other rules of lambda calculus, but is commonly used because it's useful and relatively innocuous (merely syntactic, decidable). I don't fully understand these concepts, but am taking a stab at a summary.

Comment: @MaxHeiber sounds correct. I note that eta equality is provable propositionally from function extensionality, but if we don't have funext then we can't get eta from anywhere else, and I think we get a weaker type theory. It is still usable though.

Comment: @AndrásKovács ok, maybe I am mistaken. I thought introducing the type `A->B` already establishes the meaning of equality of `\ x -> f x` and `f`, but maybe it is a straightforward consequence.